# Negative testing plus sign in url parameter

Tags: test-design, http

Are there any real locations, company headquarters, point of interest which contains a "+" plus sign in the name?

I'm looking for a real-world test to validate a webservice handles double-encoded urls properly. One of the parameters is a location that is geocoded into a lat/lon. I can't for the life of me find a single instance where this exists. (but surely there must be one)

So when users submit a url-encoded location=Some+Place vs location=Some%2BPlace I can be sure they are getting the right location.

Comment: Why not just make up your own location like you did in your question? What example are you looking for? You just want a location, company, etc. that has a '+' in it? Or you want an example url with a '+' in it?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/?#q=google+book+entry

Comment: I'm doing a geocoding lookup for real-world locations.  Addresses don't have '+' in them, but I figured there must be a location or company name that does. Something like "A+ Company".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find locations by visiting Google Maps and performing a search for "A+" for example. Here is one instance:

https://www.google.ca/maps/place/A%2B+Sushi/@45.4174868,-75.7006636,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4cce05acac9d93f1:0x72f78612d6aff3a5!8m2!3d45.4174831!4d-75.6984749

Comment: That works if I already have a name in mind with a +.  Unfortunately I dont see the ability to search for *+* in google maps.  That said, it was a clever idea.  I hadn't considered using google maps in for this type of problem.

Comment: If you use the search box in Google Maps to look for "A+", a number of suggestions will come up near you.